React native recommendation: remove package="com...." from the source AndroidManifest.xml
I'm trying to update a react native project from API 33 to 34. After go through many errors, I manage to upgrade API from 31 to 34 according to this answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/78750253/9751777
But, I having this error for almost every react-natice package in my project

Setting the namespace via the package attribute in the source AndroidManifest.xml is no longer supported


Recommendation: remove package="com...." from the source AndroidManifest.xml

I followed this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/75191686/9751777 and manage to fix this error.
But every time I run yarn install I have to modify every AndroidManifest file again and it kind of tyring.
Do we have no other solution for this type of error?
Some of my project packages that i have to modify:
@react-native-async-storage
@react-native-clipboard
@react-native-firebase/app
@react-native-firebase/analytics
@react-native-firebase/crashlytics
@react-native-firebase/database
@react-native-firebase/dynamic-links
@react-native-firebase/firestore
@react-native-firebase/messaging
@react-native-firebase/remote-config
@sayem314
react-native-background-timer
react-native-camera
react-native-device-info
react-native-document-picker    
react-native-fs

.......

Replace the top line manifest in AndroidManifest.xml file to following code.
<manifest  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.YOUR_PACKAGE_NAME" > 

But I have to do this for every module? and every time I yarn install, I have to do it again?

Which file you changing main project android/AndroidManifest.xml or node modules package AndroidManifest.xml . if you change main AndroidManifest you no need to change after yarn install

I have to change both android/AndroidManifest.xml and all the node modules package AndroidManifest.xml

because my project give error on each node module package

which react-native version you use?

I'm using react-native 0.68.5, compileSdkVersion 34, ndkVersion 20.1.5948944, gradle 8.1.1

try this
buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
minSdkVersion = 24
compileSdkVersion = 34
targetSdkVersion = 34
ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"

and use gradle 8.0.1

Thanks for ur suggestion, I try to change version of ndk, gradle and the errors gone when downgrade gradle to 7.x
